# 2 RelativeLayouts in one layout

Tags: android, events, android-relativelayout, behind

I've decided to use 2 `RelativeLayouts` for my app, one `Layout` for one portion of child `Views` on the screen to the left, the other for child `Views` to go to the right.

The problem is I don't know how to lay them out in XML so that the middle white space isn't included when I inflate my `Layout`.

[This is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeM4d.jpg)

When I use 1 `RelativeLayout`, the middle white space is filled with the `RelativeLayout`, and I can't touch anything behind it.

Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something similar to the following example.

This will create a `LinearLayout` with 2 `RelativeLayouts` using `layout_weight` to space the `RelativeLayouts` and then you can populate the `RelativeLayouts` with whatever you want.

The `Buttons` are just place holders for the example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```